# Is there any way to spin down the GPU fan with the open source drivers for a RadeonHD 5870?

Tags: 11.10, power-management, amd-graphics, noise

Is there any way to spin down the GPU fan with the open source drivers for a RadeonHD 5870?

I'm not happy with the catalyst 11.9 in 11.10.
I am happy with the open source performance, but the noise is annoying. I don't run any games.

Answer (score 1):

There is some risk of overheating the card (GPU and VRMs) if you turn off the fan completely - keep an eye on the temperatures before and after turning off the fan.  The ATI/AMD control panel should let you check this, and [gkrellm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GKrellM) also monitors GPU temperature along with many other things.

The RadeonHD 5870 is a very high-end card if you don't run games - you could save quite a bit of power and noise by replacing it with something like an [HD 5450](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5450-overview/pages/hd-5450-overview.aspx) at $50, which has fanless (passive) versions available.  Unless perhaps you boot into Windows for games, in which case ignore this :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always open terminal and type in

aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 ###"

replace the #'s with the fanspeed percenteage you want.

for example if you want you want to have your fan run at 35% speed you'd open terminal and type in

aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 35"

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set a lower power profile for your Radeon. I'm running on a laptop with Mobility Radeon X1600 and setting it to low has helped to reduce both the power consumption and lower the fan usage.

I'm using profile-based frequency switching in 11.04-11.10 by running:

```
$ sudo -i # you need interactive root session for this
# echo profile > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
# exit # exit sudo mode
```

To make your selected profile apply on startup put in `/etc/rc.local`. Look for more info on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI#With_KMS_enabled).